# iOS 10 no longer starts lock screen music player when headphones inserted

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, ios

Before installing iOS 10, whenever I plugged in my headphones (or car adapter), the lock screen music player would pop up (which is very convenient).  Was this a deliberate change to the OS, or some problem specific to me?  Is there some way to reenable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be deliberate, I miss the feature too as it will not appear whether I use wired or bluetooth connection.

I could not find a way to reenable it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed in 10.2.1, sort of.  It now works most of the time, but I can't figure out what causes it to work or not.